# GWT performance issue in IE with paneles

Tags: java, gwt

Even when loading 60 records IE8/9 takes so long where firefox load them quite fast. In this module construct a grid look using GWT panel. Any one face similar performance issue like slowness in IE with GWT?

Comment: You'll probably get better feedback by showing us the code used, and concrete timings rather than "so long" and "quite fast".

Comment: Everything is always SLOW in IE compared to Chrome/Firefox !!!!

Comment: @SSR That is a very outdated information.

Comment: GWT/Javascript for ie6-ie8 is extremely slow. IE9 might do better,but majority user are stuck on windows xp / ie8.

Comment: @his IE6/7/8 aren't getting any faster as time goes on, IE9 is merely not great, and while there aren't a lot of users running those older browsers, many of us still need to support them.

Answer (score 2):

IE6 has very old javaScript interpreter. So It will be always slow. Best what can you do - optimize your code, reduce client calculations, etc..

Try `-optimize 9` compiler parameter. It can also help.

Also you can try to apply advices from [GWT official documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOptimizing).

Comment: even with IE8/9 i can see this

Answer (score 0):

**Compared to other browsers  ie is very slow**, the sentance alone doesnt make you satisfy.

But the fact is the below ie9 versions have very slow `JAVASCRIPT Parser`.So obviously will take some moretime to rendering time.

How ever the Microsoft people cameup with an faster parser from their release of IE9.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/18/the-new-javascript-engine-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx

As the data loading from server is same in all browsers, we have fewer chances to speed up by reducing no of `DOM ELEMENT` creation if possible.
For instance getting the dom element setting the value instead of creating new one.

Comment: thanks baadshah. actually even with IE8/9 i can see this slowness.

Comment: @harshana true.some rendering time increased but not completely..what we can do is reducing no of lines of code in onsuccess.plese paste your code , so that someone can find loopholes...:)